# Get same JAVA compilation error as in PowerShell or CMD in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm on latest Windows 10. I have JDK 15. Latest Visual Studio Code (System). In VS Code, I have half of the Java Extension Pack Installed, i.e Language Support for Java (Red Hat) | Debugger for Java (Microsoft) | Visual Studio IntelliCode (Microsoft). So I did that to just get that run button on the top right (the default installed VS Code didn't have that run button for JAVA programs), below the close button, to that I can run the JAVA programs inside the VS Code. I didn't wanna go out to the directory then open Power Shell or CMD and then write java filename.java and run the program...

Now the issue is that when I click the run button, I think, a Power Shell is opened inside the VS Code and then something other than "java FileName.java" is being written. Because of that I can't really see what the compilation error is. I can only see the [line number where the problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC4Fk.png), not actually the solution for that. || If I run the same in the PowerShell outside the VS Code with this "java FileName.java", I can see that there is [some issue at x line and also the solution for the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RjZX.png)

So I wanted to know if there is any way to get [this type of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RjZX.png) inside the [Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC4Fk.png).
Or if there is any way that Instead of writing a lot of thing like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC4Fk.png), we can simple tell the Visual Studio Code to run "java fileName.java" inside VS Code when I click the Run Button at the top.

EDIT:

The Code that I'm running is this one.....
File Name - test.java

```
import java.io.*; 
public class SOPFileTest{ 
public static void main(String arr[]){
    try{
        // Creating a File object that represents the disk file. 
        PrintStream o = new PrintStream(new File("A.txt")); 

        // Store current System.out before assigning a new value 
        PrintStream console = System.out; 

        // Assign o to output stream 
        System.setOut(o); 
        System.out.println("Test 1"); 

        // Use stored value for output stream 
        System.setOut(console); 
        System.out.println("Test 2"); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }  
}
```

Now I've noticed somethings, they are:

-When (FileName == Class Name)
---Then (VS Code)
-----Prints the Last System.out.println in the console
-----A.txt is not created / written inside
---Then (Powershell)
-----Prints the Last System.out.println in the console
-----A.txt is created and/or written inside

-When (FileName != Class Name)
---Then (VS Code)
-----shows the error same as the image that I included above.
---Then (Powershell)
-----Prints the Last System.out.println in the console
-----A.txt is created and/or written inside

So powershell works as I intend it would, the VS Code isn't...

Comment: Can you post the code for me to reproduce your question? if it's convenient.

Comment: Yep... I edited he question....

Answer (score 0):

If the filename is different from ClassName, java extension will detect it and throws probelms, which is build failed and you can choose if continue:
[image]

If you choose proceed, there should be:
[image]

**[UPDATE -- Screenshot in Powershell:]**
[image]

It's about the same as problems shown in VS Code.

Java extension requires **class must be defined in its own file, so filename should be as the same as ClassName**, then everything works well, no matter in integrated Terminal in VS Code, or in the PowerShell outside VS Code:
[image]

[image]

> So I wanted to know if there is any way to get this type of output
> inside the Visual Studio Code.

Keeping the filename and classname same makes sure it could be built and compiled successfully, which is the first step.

And the text file should be generated in current working directory, check it in your file explorer.

Comment: Ah yes.... I noticed that and did change the class name.... I made it same.. But the thing that I wanna do is that, instead of the error display like "Exception in thread 'main'..." (Pic 2 of this answer), I wanna see the error that is displayed in PS "Uncaught Exception in 'main'..." (Second pic that I kept in the Question). I want the **error messages** to be the **same in Integrated Terminal in VS Code** as in **PS outside VS code**... Hope you got what I meant...

Comment: @SreyasC.V. I've update the screenshots in powershell, you can try to compile it again and the error content is almost the same as problems in VS Code.

Comment: I don't think you still got that.... I wanna see the error message of Pic 3 inside the Integrated Terminal of VS Code. I don't wanna see the error message of Pic 2. And this question was never about the error in the program, it is about getting the same error message in both terminals.

Comment: Okay, to be simple, because in Powershell, only jdk works, but in vscode, jdk and extensions work both. so the error will be a little different in description but the main meaning are the same.